# Como puedo solucionar el error en el Program.cs al cambiar de Form en c#?

Tags: c#

tengo un gran problema y es que intento cambiar de form y cerrar el primero (no quiero usar el Hide() porque pues quiero liberar esa memoria) pero en el Program.cs me lansa un error:
**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**, segun dice que no hay una instancia del objeto pero no se a que se puede referir aqui les dejo mi codigo:
Ya lo intente con this.Close Dispose y no funciona no se porque si alguien tiene alguna solucion le agradeceria su ayuda.

Estuve modificando un poco el Program.cs y al final me quedo algo asi gg pero no me funciona nada.

Eh probado de todo pero no funciona no se que mas hacer.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ControlUsuario;
using connectorMySQL;

namespace PVF
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        Conexion connection;
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("¿Estas seguro que deseas salir?", "¡Alerta!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        private void bttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nam = txtBoxUser.Text;
            string pas = txtBoxPass.Text;
            Usuario user1 = new Usuario(nam, pas, "Admin");
            IniciarSesion(user1);
        }
        public void IniciarSesion(Usuario usu)
        {
            if (!usu.Nombre.Equals("") & !usu.Clave.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario/Contraseña incorrecta!");
                return;
            }
            menuPrincipal menP = new menuPrincipal(usu);
            menP.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new Conexion();
            if (!connection.InitConnection("root", ""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al conectar a la Base de Datos");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Pero no has puesto el codigo del Program.cs, nos has puesto el codigo del formulario de Login.
Tambien estaria bien que nos dijeras exactamente en que linea te da el error, eso lo puedes ver Depurando el codigo.